# How to balance Corda DB and Flow Executions?

Tags: corda, cordite

I have a few 1000 transactions in my Corda Enterprise Node, The node is in a 16GB ram system dedicated only for the node.

Questions are as follows

1. what would be the optimized Pagination that can be used for Maximum Performance to pick the transactions?
2. Also would it impact the flow executions as once I pick up the State I am using it as an input for another flow execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Please visit our site for more information about optimizing node performance: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/operating/optimizing.html#optimizing-node-performance

As Corda Enterprise is slight different with the open source over the network setups, and capability of multi-threading. RAM play less weight over the performance for an Corda Enterprise setup.

To your second question: UTXO model natural inherits the idea of having the previous output as the input of future transaction. However, in Corda, you are not necessarily "pick up" the state and doing anything with it. You are only passing in a `StateAndRef` object. The read and write to the original state is very minimal (only change the status from `UNCONSUMED` to `CONSUMED`). Performance wise, it is not really implicating the performance.